# SQL Query in PHP not returning expected result

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query users Level but I'm not able to return an `int`. I have no idea why because when I echo the result it gives is i.e "1"

```
function lvl_chcek($username)
{
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'idoctor_db');

    $lvl = $db->query('
    SELECT Level
    FROM users
    WHERE Login = "'.$username.'"
    ');

    echo $lvl->fetch_object()->Level;

    return $lvl->fetch_object()->Level;

}
```

I also tried this but I get `NULL`

```
function lvl_chcek($username)
{
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'idoctor_db');

    $query = $db->query('
    SELECT Level
    FROM users
    WHERE Login = "'.$username.'"
    ');
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $lvl = $array['Level'];

    echo $lvl;

    return $lvl;
}
```

Comment: In your first example, where is `$lvl` supposed to magically appear from?

Comment: Each call to `fetch_object` fetches a row. The first time you call it will return a different result then the second time you call it. In your second piece of code, you're mixing mysql and mysqli functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per mysqli <kbd>[doc](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query)</kbd> you need to query after that you need to fetch the result.

try this:

```
function lvl_chcek($username)
{
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'idoctor_db');

   $query = $db->query('
    SELECT Level
     FROM users
     WHERE Login = "'.$username.'"
     LIMIT 1');
   
    $obj = $query->fetch_object();
    return $obj->Level;

}
```

it should return user level.